# Range optimizations opportunities

Tags: rust, compiler-optimization

Those two functions have the same behavior, however compiler optimizes those differently.

- With [RangeInclusive](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeInclusive.html):

```rust
pub fn sum_positive_1(n: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut acc = 0;

    for i in 1..=n {
        acc += i
    }

    acc
}
```

- With [Range](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html)

```rust
pub fn sum_positive_2(n: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut acc = 0;

    for i in 1..n + 1 {
        acc += i
    }

    acc
}
```

[Assembly produced](https://godbolt.org/z/hbbf36Tja).

---

As you can see in the assembly, the compiler optimizes the loop in `sum_positive_2`. However, it does not in `sum_positive_1`.

- `sum_positive_1` has O(N) complexity.
- `sum_positive_2` has O(1) complexity, because the closed-form is used.

Indeed, simple benchmark on my machine:

- `sum_positive_1(1048576)` -> execution `2.1158 ms`
- `sum_positive_2(1048576)` -> execution `3.4063 ns`

---

Why `RangeInclusive` inhibits this kind of optimization?

Comment: [This is also a worth of read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70514035/6699447) but it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does iteration over an inclusive range generate longer assembly in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70672533/why-does-iteration-over-an-inclusive-range-generate-longer-assembly-in-rust) (Oh, I could have just voted earlier; didn't realize this was missing any tags I had a gold badge in.)

Comment: No, it doesn’t, actually.