# Indexing in Rust ndarray crate based on a boolean mask

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, rust, indexing, boolean

I would like to efficiently index into an ndarray using a boolean mask. To better convey what I mean I have some working numpy code and then my attempt in rust ndarray which works but is extremely inefficient.

Numpy:

```
import numpy as np

shape = (100, 100, 100)

grouping_array = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=shape)
data_array = np.random.rand(*shape)

for i in range(1, 100):
    ith_mean = data_array[grouping_array == i].mean()
    print(ith_mean)
```

Rust ndarray:

```
fn group_means(
    data: &Array<f32, IxDyn>,
    grouping_var: &Array<f32, IxDyn>,
    n_groups: i32,
) {
    
    for group in 1..n_groups {
        
        let index_array = grouping_var.mapv(|x| x == roi as f32);
        let roi_data = Array::from_iter(
            image_data
            .iter()
            .zip(index_array.iter())
            .map(|(x, y)| if *y { *x } else { 0. })
        );
        
        let mean_roi = roi_data.mean().unwrap();
        println!("group {}; mean {}", group, mean_roi);
    
    }    
}
```

Here each iteration in the n_groups loop takes about as long as the whole numpy script which is done in less than a second. Is there a better way to do this in the rust-ndarray version?

Comment: This is the obligatory 'did you run with `--release` comment for the performance test' comment.

Comment: I am sorry, yes that was the main problem. However, even with `--release` and after installing using `cargo install --path .`, it is still noticeably slower than the numpy version (between 1 or 2 seconds slower). That can be for a number of reasons I guess, but thought if there is a more efficient/idiomatic way of doing it in rust, that will be good. But yeah, with the compiler optimisations even this will be good enough for now. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Do you feel this is answering the question enough, or are you still seeking a faster alternative? If you don't, I can close this as a duplicate of the canonical [Why is my Rust program slower than the equivalent Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255736/why-is-my-rust-program-slower-than-the-equivalent-java-program)

Comment: I think i would still like to see if someone as a better way of doing the slicing as this is still quite a bit slower even with optimisations.

Comment: I don't know if numpy relies on the current processor to perform optimizations, but try setting the environment variable `RUSTFLAGS="-Ctarget-cpu=native"` before building (you don't need `cargo install`).

Comment: thanks! tried that out now, did not really change the performance. I think my code is just not as efficient as it could be, but its probably not an easy solution. Will have to do some more systematic performance testing.

Comment: Are these two pieces of code even equivalent? Does the numpy version consider values that line up with a "false" to be zero? Or are they omitted entirely? The Rust version considers them to be zero, but if the Python code omits them, this will produce a different result when you ask for the mean.

Comment: And i just realised my rust code isnt even correct in terms of calculating the mean since i include the zeros in the elements in the mean calculation even though they shouldnt be

Comment: Yes you are right @cdhowie i have to get back to the drawing board sorry. I just cannot for the life of me do this indexing correctly in ndarray

Comment: @Leo Using filter_map instead of map should be sufficient. You just return `None` instead of 0, and `Some(*x)` instead of `*x`.

Comment: ok yes that works, at least its correct then for now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not a surprise to others, but since my `grouping_var` array should (in my use case) always be 3D array, I changed its type (and therefore also `index_array`) from &Array<f32, IxDyn> to &Array<f32, Ix3> which dramatically improved performance.